# Travelling with hiking poles as checked-in luggage

Tags: tips-and-tricks, hiking, trekking, backpacks, fragile-luggage

I'll be going on a hiking trip soon. The backpack is small and I'm going to keep it with me as a carry on. The hiking poles telescope down, but still stick out of the bag. Plus I've read hiking poles aren't allowed in carry on. Anyone have ideas on how to check hiking poles by themselves...would a garbage bag suffice?

Comment: I wonder if this might be better on [the Great Outdoors stackexchange site](http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I don't think a garbage bag would work well, since the pointy end of the poles would tend to poke through.  What about a cardboard box?

Comment: If your collapsed poles stick out of your bag, is it big enough for everything else you should be carrying?

Comment: @NateEldredge good point...no pun intended;)

Comment: @MichaelHampton bag should be fine. Its a pretty light trip. I'm hiking (part of) the camino in spain. I'll be staying in hostels along the way, so no tent, cookset, minimal consumables...the bag is 28L....should be fine for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind hauling it around at the other end (or discarding and looking for another when its time to go home) maybe a cardboard or plastic tube of the type used for transporting blueprints and art (any art store should carry the type shown below). Some of them might be useful transporting other stuff with a backpack so it wouldn't be totally wasted.

[image: https://www.currys.com/catalogpc.htm?Category=PLASTIC_STORAGE_TUBES&Source=Search]

Or you could pack it in bubble wrap with a sturdy wood dowel or two to keep it from being bent. My biggest worry with expensive hiking poles is that they might end up all bent out of shape and unable to telescope out (or buckled and completely ruined). If they're just bent a bit you can always straighten them.

Comment: +1 I would stuff the tube with newspaper or bubble wrap, to render it more resistant to being squashed.

Comment: @Spehro Pefhany yeah, I think the only problem will be getting it to the other end...Maybe I'll mail it ahead

Comment: @JoErNanO good call on the bubble wrap or newspaper...I'm sure newspaper would be easy to find too

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would package them tightly together using generous amounts of bubble-wrap and heavy-duty scotch tape. The more bubble-wrap the better. This way the sharp edges of the poles will be safely contained, and the package together will be bulky enough as to reduce the chances of damaging it (bending the poles) if weight is applied on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually dismantle many of the telescoping poles and when you do, they are even  shorter than when telescoped up. Be sure to try this at the shop (or at home) before you travel so that you know what to expect (some have fiddly bits that come out when you unscrew them).